# Passing sub document to view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

in my schema where i have company with sub document PostedJobs of type array 
all companies of are passed to user view

Get Company

```
router.get('/',  isLoggedIn ,  function(req, res, next) {
    Company.find({'Creator': req.user.id}).then(function(companies) {
        res.render('Company', { "Companies" : companies });
    });
});
```

after getting a specific company i get that company by name which is unique

```
router.get('/:name' , isLoggedIn , function(req , res , next) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    Company.findOne({Name : name}).then(function(Company) {
        res.render('dashboard',{
            "Company" : Company
        });
    });
});
```

with this view i want to also pass PostedJob into company view

Comment: can you please add some example documents to make your question more clear?

Comment: Well mate posted jobs is a field inside mongoose schema where i can post jobs related to company

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Sub document is present in page and you can access it as i access it as following

```
<% Company.PostedJobs.forEach(function(Job ,index){%> 
                                  <tr>
                                   <td><%= index+1 %></td>
                                  <td><%=Job.JobName %></td>
                                  <td><%=Job.JobType %></td>
                                  <td><%=Job.JobLocation %></td>
                                  <td><%=Job.JobSalary %></td>
                                  </tr>
                                <%}) %>
```